# Textboxvalidation: Empty or minimum 3 characters (spaces do not count)

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have some textboxes I'm using as search-fields.
The textbox can be empty, but when a search-criteria is filled in, it must be at least 3 characters long, ignoring the spaces in the count.

I've found that a regularexpressionvalidator validates true when the textbox is empty, so that part is ok.

**Q:** regex for a minimumlenth of 3 characters. Spaces are allowed, but should not count in the length.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
'(\s*\w\s*){3}'
```

This regular expression looks for a character (`\w`) optionally surronded by any whitespace (`\s*`) three times (`{3}`), which is what you're looking for.

Note: I don't know asp.net, but I think the regular expression is all you need to solve the problem.

Comment: This is indeed working. One additional question here: I'm using an asterix (*) as wildcard. Is it possible to ommit that character also from the count?

Comment: @Koen Sure, to match either a whitespace or a start, replace `\s` with `[\s*]`: `'([\s*]*\w[\s*]*){3}'`