# Textboxvalidation - regularexpressionvalidator including accented letters

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

A while ago I've asked a question regarding textboxvalidation with regex ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815580/textboxvalidation-empty-or-minimum-3-characters-spaces-do-not-count)).
So according to the answer, I use a (clientside) regularexpressionvalidator with the following regex:

```
([\s*]*\w[\s*]*){3,}
```

Which worked as expected unless a word with accents is entered ( eg *élè*) for searching élève.
In that case the validation is not passed.

Can someone help me out on how to include accented letters in the above regex?
Some pages tells that `\w` should include accented letters, however when I test it with an [online validator](http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp) it fails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\s*[a-zA-Z_0-9À-ÿ]\s*){3,}
```

OR

```
([\s*]*[a-zA-Z_0-9À-ÿ][\s*]*){3,}
```

**This will include all characters from À to ÿ (all accent characers including French accents in uppercase and lowercase)**

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I can't get those Regex in my mind. But very occasionally I do need it...

Comment: You are my hero.  Every where else I've looked, people are saying to use \p{L}.  Which for some reason doesn't seem to work in the asp regex validator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\p{L}` instead of `\w`. This would allow all characters in the Unicode "Letter" category. You might have to include number manually (`\p{N}`). (See [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock))